# Azure Policy alias for redis cache not found - terraform azure devops

Tags: azure, caching, redis, azure-devops, terraform

For some reason, get-azpolicyalias reports these aliases as being available but Azure policy does not recognize them:

```
Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/privateEndpoint
Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/privateEndpoint.id
Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/privateLinkServiceConnectionState
Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status                        Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/privateLinkServiceConnectionState.description                         Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/privateLinkServiceConnectionState.actionsRequired
Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections/provisioningStateas
```

So when I run my code I get an error stating the alias does not exist:

***The 'field' property 'Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections[*]' of the policy rule doesn't exist as an alias under provider 'Microsoft.Cache' and resource type 'redis'.***

```
policy_rule: >
    {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Cache/redis"
          },
          {
            "count": {
                "field": "Microsoft.Cache/redis/privateEndpointConnections[*]"

            },
            "equals": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Policy alias for redis cache not found - terraform azure devops

As I know, Azure Cache for Redis is in "Private Preview" for this feature:

[Azure Cache for Redis with Azure Private Link (Public Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-private-link)

And Private endpoint is not available for Azure Redis Cache. You can see the list of services made generally available:

[Announcing Azure Private Link GA for Azure Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/privatelinkforpaasga/)

- Azure Storage
- Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2
- Azure SQL Database
- Azure Cosmos DB
- Azure Synapse Analytics (SQL Data Warehouse)
- Azure Key Vault
- Azure Database for MySQL
- Azure Database for PostgreSQL
- Azure Database for MariaDB
- Azure Kubernetes Service -> Kubernetes API

In addition, Private Link is now available in preview for the following services:

- App Service
- Azure Cognitive Search
- Event Hub
- Service Bus
- Azure Relay
- Azure Backup
- Azure Container Registry
- Event Grid -> Topics
- Event Grid -> Domains